# jQuery - selectors on a html string

Tags: jquery, html, string, jquery-selectors

I am going to get a element from a html-string with jQuery, but I always get an undefined in my console.
My String is:

```
<td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td>
```

and I want to get the td.test.

I've tested:

```
console.log($('.test', '<td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td>').innerHTML);
console.log($('.test', '<td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td>').html());
console.log($('.test', '<td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td>').first().innerHTML);
```

and some more, but nothing works :/

Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

Comment: Maybe you should wrap your string with jQuery first?

Comment: Can you show me [where it's documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) that jQuery should be able to accept arbitrary HTML as the second argument to `$`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

First, use `jQuery.parseHTML` to parse the HTML into an array of elements; then you’ll be able to convert it to a jQuery collection and use `filter` to restrict the collection to elements matching a selector.

```js
var html =
    '<td class="test">asd</td>' +
    '<td class="second">fgh</td>' +
    '<td class="last">jkl</td>';

var text = $($.parseHTML(html)).filter('.test').text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `parseHTML` is no longer necessary, it will work without it (jQuery > 3.5)

Answer (score 10):

You can't use jQuery selectors on a collection of nodes like this. You can wrap in a single node to work around this, so just add e.g. a wrapping `<tr>` node.

```
var htmlBits = '<tr>'
  + '<td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td>'
  + '</tr>';
```

And then it will work:

```
console.log($('.test', htmlBits).text()); // outputs 'asd'
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgjy75o3/) (remember to view the console to see the log).

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
console.log($('<td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td>').filter('.test').html());
```

or:

```
console.log($('.test', '<table><td class="test">asd</td><td class="second">fgh</td><td class="last">jkl</td></table>').html());
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a response that is of the form:

```
<div>...
</div>

<div>...
</div>

<div>...
</div>
```

And @minitech 's method resulted in an array of HTML nodes in which the selector didn't work.

**So I tried this and it worked out nice**:

```
$.ajax({
    url:
    success: function($data) {
         var $parsed_data = $('<div/>').append($data);
         var found = $parsed_data.find(".Selector");
         ...
    }
});
```