# How to get the value from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like follows in javascript

```
var str='<img class="avatar  avatar-small 012345" src="/img/staff_avatar_profile.jpg" />&nbsp; olah blah';
```

I need to get every time the number like for this example 012345. Which will be ofcourse be different in different scenario and I also need to get the text olah blah which will be also different in different scenario.

I have the above string in a variable. ;)

How can i perform this in a efficient manner in java-script

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I assume you mean the numeric class?

Comment: I know but I gave that in a variable string

Comment: So that is stored in a variable? That's very relevant info!

Comment: Oh thank u ...i added in my question

Comment: a class identifier can not be numeric as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors. So no framework/library would work here if its not doing wrong behaivours. Use substring or regex instead, when you always know the characters before and behind the number.

Comment: @tymeJV he did say, "I have a string like follows in javascript" please explain how this is possible without a variable

Comment: @RoryPicko92 It 's edited now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery if it works there to get an only numeric class name. Take a look at [jQuery - selectors on a html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551230/jquery-selectors-on-a-html-string) to get a clue.

Comment: I like this the best. When I do $(myString).find('.user').text()..it returns me nothing....

Comment: @SaurabhKumar, then please check this answer as useful :)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to parse HTML in a browser is to let the browser do it for you:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var numbers = div.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].className.match(/ (\d+)/)[1];
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGuLC/1/

Comment: Its nice but very fragile if i have other numbers also sometimes in my string

Comment: @SaurabhKumar - the regex will only match the first set of number it can find.

Answer (score 0):

Use the data attribute instead of class.

```
<img class="avatar  avatar-small" data-id="012345" src="/img/staff_avatar_profile.jpg" />
```

Then use jQuery to get the data attribute.

```
jQuery('.avatar').data('id');
```

**Sources:**
http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/
http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: he has string not html image

Comment: And also didn't mention jQuery anywhere

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a string or an element. He can still create a html element in jQuery and then access the data attribute that way.

Comment: @CharliePrynn yes ,that's the reason why i told him this , because i was trying to convert string to dom element.The difference between me and you is that i tried to parse string without div , can you tell me why ?

Comment: I'm not sure I undertand what you mean @FaceOfJock.

Comment: why not var div = document.createElement('<img src ... ...');

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store data for an element, one good way to achieve that is to use the data-key attribute with jQuery:

```
$('.avatar').data('number', '012345'); // set value
var number = $('.avatar').data('number'); // get value
```

The rendered markup will look like this:

```
<img class="avatar  avatar-small" data-number="012345" src="/img/staff_avatar_profile.jpg" />
```