# Use jQuery selectors to target and replace elements in a string containing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, dom

I have a string that contains HTML, for example

```
var myString = "<div><p>testing</p></div>";
```

I need to target `p` and replace "testing" with something else, say "Hello World". I would normally use

```
$("p").innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

However, this is part of a string, not part of the DOM. How can I use jQuery's selector system to select from a string of HTML?

Comment: This does not look like it's a duplicate of that. He even stated he's not using jQuery.

Comment: Question 1: Do you have a DOM or are you doing something fancy out of a DOM?  Question 2: Are you adverse to "hacky" solutions like having a place holder in the DOM and using that?

Comment: @JonP In my case I have a template that I pull as text into a variable with AJAX and I want to add content to a part of that template before putting it in the template's holder in the real DOM. I'd normally target it with jQuery, but it's still in a variable. I can add it to the DOM and then place content in it, but it will be more tricky to target the exact one and there might be a few milliseconds where there is no content.

Comment: The correct way to do this using jquery is `var s = '<li>text</li>'; $.parseHTML(s).find("p").text("Hello World")`. Not sure why this question is marked a duplicate of one that does not ask for the jquery method of doing this

Answer (score 1):

You can turn any HTML into a parse-able jQuery object(s).

[jQuery - selectors on a html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551230/jquery-selectors-on-a-html-string)

```
$('p', myString).text()
```

Comment: That allows me to retrieve the string but not edit it (as meni181818 mentioned in his answer). +1 as it is useful.

Answer (score -1):

note that you **cant** use:

```
$("p", myString).text( "Hello World" );
```

because is not 'Editable' DOM (`isContentEditable: false`)

Comment: It looks like you were downvoted by someone else because that is more of a comment than an answer. I suggest deleting the answer and posting it as a comment.